# Unable to grab specific digits from the string

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a long string which I am reading from the web element. Trying to Grab an ID from the string. Following is the string
"Comm id: 681
Flat ₺ 25.00 per/player
Only Positive Commissions Calculated"

I read the element and get the text of the string and store in a string. Then try to use Regex to split and then parsing the string.

```
string aa = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='FRMcommissionupdate']/div[7]/div")).Text;
                string[] numbers = Regex.Split(aa, @"\D+");
                int value = int.Parse(aa);
                return value;
```

I am expecting the output as 681 only. But it keeps failing

Comment: `it keeps failing` what does this mean? It doesn't work as you expect or is throwing an exception or ??? If there's an error message, you should post that. Make sure that you edit your question and put all that in there and not in comments.

Comment: On a side note, you should always strive to have well named variables that can be easily understood. Unless `aa` means something specific to you, it's probably not a good variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

```
string aa = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='FRMcommissionupdate']/div[7]/div")).Text;
var result = new string(aa.SkipWhile(x => 
                       !char.IsDigit(x)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
return result;
```